# Is it good practice in JavaScript to switch the data type of a previously assigned variable? Or is it a matter of preference?

Tags: javascript, variables, standards

I'm new to JavaScript so I was curious about the flexibility of JS variable assignment.

Using the following code as an example:

```
var container = "hello";
container = 43;
```

Is it good practice (or a common practice) to change the data type of a variable in JavaScript? Or is it a matter of preference?

Comment: It's very common; idiomatic, even. It doesn't hurt anything. The variables themselves don't seem to mind.

Comment: Depends. I usually prefer to have variables carrying a certain semantic. So if I have `userRecords`, I expect the value to be some kind of list. Assigning a boolean to it would be very strange.

Comment: <3 @Pointy: "The variables themselves don't seem to mind."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript gives you lots of rope.  You can either build a masterpiece with that rope or you can write horrible code.  Because the language does not stop you from doing bad things, you must know when different things in the language are appropriate or inappropriate.

To that end, the use or purpose of the variable should match its name and should not change. In other words, you should not use the same variable for many different purposes.

If you have a different use, then create a different variable and give that new variable a different descriptive name that describes its use.

It is possible to have a single variable that has a consistent use that fits with one descriptive name and that use can contain different types, but that is not particularly common. Most of the time you're using different types, it's because you have a different use that would fit better in a different variable.

I tend to think of my coding objectives in this order:

1. Correct, reliable code
2. Clear, easy to understand, maintainable and extensible code
3. Appropriate performance for the situation
4. Concise and compact

Note that clear, maintainable code is given a fairly high priority.  This will allow me to come back and work on this code years later to fix a bug or add a feature and still understand how it works.  Or, it will allow someone else on the team to work on the code immediately and have little trouble understanding how it works or how to modify it safely.

Overloading the same variable for multiple purposes with different types is unlikely to be clear and easy to understand and maintain.  I'm not saying that there is never an OK situation to do that, but the code better make it very, very clear that that is expected and a possibility as this will usually not be the case.

---

Note, in your code example, the name of your variable `container` is not descriptive for either of your uses when it contains `"hello"` or `43`.

Comment: What is about performance in this case? I guess it saves some bit of memory - at speed costs?

Comment: @Lenny - No tiny amount of possible performance gain (if it's even noticeable) is worth writing confusing, hard-to-maintain code.  It's just not a tradeoff worth considering.

Answer (score 2):

While the language totally allows you to do that, I would avoid it as much as possible. It is just error prone and misleading. Usually the variable name will describe its contents and if you pass something totally different I consider you are abusing the language features.

In JS there is the concept of `duck typing`, for instance if you have:

```
function doStuff(myComplexType){
   var i = myComplexType.myProperty;
}
```

It does not matter what the actual type of `myComplexObject` is as long as it satisfies the *contract* and has a `myProperty` defined.

Comment: should your function have a name or be assigned to a var?

Comment: in this example, it doesn't matter at all.

Answer (score 1):

It's always better to be consistent. Especially if you work in a team. It can really frustrate people who has to walk through your code, because sometimes people just don't have time and they jump from one place to another, so it's very easy to not notice that kind of changes in the code.

Also, never mix data types in the array. Believe me, you don't want to be that guy.

Answer (score -1):

It is a "good practice" to use the same variable for the same type of data. Especially, don't mixup types in an array, as the javascript engines like V8(chrome) and SpiderMonkey(Firefox) optimize your code at runtime, and mixed-types in array (among other things) won't let that happen. You'd also like to build up this habit, so that later, if you're using things like [Typed Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays), it would come in handy.

But pedanticism aside, you can play fast and loose with javascript, as it is [designed that way](https://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/A_Short_History_of_JavaScript). Sometimes, it is unavoidable too, as an argument in a function may have an integer as it's argument or, if not passed, then 'undefined', which is <del>an object</del> not an integer!

Have fun with JS, it's a pretty fun language to learn, and fast to experiment with.

Comment: `undefined` is not an `object`.

Comment: Not in the normal sense, i agree. It is a property on the global object. BUT, `Object.prototype.toString.call(undefined); === "[object Undefined]"`

Comment: typeof undefined === "undefined"